# Get a list of all available classes in the JVM in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark and have added a couple of jars to `$SPARK_HOME/jars` but I am getting `py4j.protocol.Py4JError: ClassName does not exist in the JVM` error.

Is there a way I can list all the classes in jvm (`sc._jvm`)?

Comment: I think this is a version issue with PySpark, try downgrading the version once

Comment: if that doesnt work alone add a PYTHONPATH system environment variable with value `%SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-<version>-src.zip:%PYTHONPATH%` dont forget to edit this value accordingly

Comment: I tried the same with 2.3.0. Got the same error. I'll try with 2.4.0

Comment: I think py4j packages its own version, so you need to make sure there are no compatibility issues between versions. I had the same problem with the versions of Apache spark and PySpark

Comment: @UlugToprak, I downgraded to 2.3.0. It's working now! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have already fixed the issue by downgrading the PySpark version, I am just posting this answer for context and future reference.

The are no simultaneous stable spark releases with the current version of PySpark 2.4.0 and using different versions of spark causes compatibility issues.

I suggest first check the PySpark version and make sure it matches the spark version.

You should also add PYTHONPATH system environment variable with the value 
`%SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-<version>-src.zip:%PYTHONPATH%`

spark/python/lib contains the py4j version information that you can edit the version part of the variable above